# R: Leave rows in a df based on a specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

Lets assume a df like this:

```
X   VAL
1    a
2    b
5    a
9    b
32   a
33   b
40   b
42   a
```

I want to drop all rows where the *X[i+1]-X[i] != 1* where I compare grouped pairs (first I look at rows 1-2 then rows 3-4, etc.) and at the same time there has to be *VAL = a* in a first row of the pair and *VAL = b* in the second row of the pair. Resulting df should look like this:

```
X   VAL
1    a
2    b
32   a
33   b
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are these paired rows? Where you might consider rows 1-2 together (diff 1 keep), then rows 3-4 together (diff 4 remove)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, gonna edit the question. I assume there is an even number of entries. So I want to start by looking at rows 1-2 then 3-4...exactly as you say.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at pairs of rows, you can `group_by` 2 rows at a time, and `filter` (keep) rows where the difference is 1.

**Edit**: Answer also checks to make sure the `first` row within a pair is 'a' and the `last` row within the pair is 'b'.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(cumsum(row_number() %% 2)) %>%
  filter(diff(X) == 1 && first(VAL) == 'a' && last(VAL) == 'b') %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(X, VAL)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      X VAL  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3    32 a    
4    33 b
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(1, 2, 5, 9, 32, 33, 40, 42), VAL = c("a", 
"b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
df[c(diff(df$x),0) == 1, ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This doesn't help tho. If you apply it at the df defined by Ben (below) you can see it leaves you with only two rows.
Anyway I edited the question so it might be clearer now.